# Why JOptionPane cannot stop flow of execution, in my application?

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
String nmEmp = fName.getText();
if(nmEmp.trim().isEmpty() || nmEmp.trim().equals("")){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empty Name", "Name Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
}
```

Why JOptionPane cannot stop flow of execution, in my application ?  And java keep running to executing code below JOptionPane, if JOptionPane execution in true condition. And what reason, this happen?. Please help, Thank you

Comment: What do you think the difference is between `String.isEmpty()` and `String.equals("")`?

Comment: Does the dialog display?

Comment: Yes, dialog can display, but still executing code below JOptionPane.

Comment: Thank you @Andy Turner for your fast response

Answer (score -1):

From Java documentation JOptionPane : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

> **Direct Use:**
>
> To create and use an JOptionPane directly, the standard pattern is
>   roughly as follows:
>
> ```
>  JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
>  pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
>  JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
>  dialog.show();
>  Object selectedValue = pane.getValue();
>  if(selectedValue == null)
>    return CLOSED_OPTION;
>  //If there is not an array of option buttons:
>  if(options == null) {
>    if(selectedValue instanceof Integer)
>       return ((Integer)selectedValue).intValue();
>    return CLOSED_OPTION;
>  }
>  //If there is an array of option buttons:
>  for(int counter = 0, maxCounter = options.length;
>     counter < maxCounter; counter++) {
>     if(options[counter].equals(selectedValue))
>     return counter;
>  }
>  return CLOSED_OPTION;
> ```

Comment: Thank you @ Mickael B, for your help

Comment: This does not answer the question.